# how to load json data returned via ajax call in custom modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm newbie and wanna favor that is I have a link to open a custom modal dialog( not a bootstrap modal) as following

```
<a href="#edit_quiz"></a>

<div class="uk-modal" id="edit_quiz">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <form:form method="post" commandName="quiz" htmlEscape="false" cssClass="uk-form-stacked">
            <div class="uk-margin-medium-bottom">
                <label for="task_title">Quiz Title</label>
                <form:hidden path="quizId"/>
                <form:input type="text" cssClass="md-input" id="quiz_title" path="quizTitle"/>                    
            </div>                
            <div class="uk-margin-medium-bottom">
                <label for="task_description">Description</label>
                <form:textarea cssClass="md-input" id="quiz_description" path="quizDescription"/>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
                <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-flat-primary" id="quiz_new_save" value="Update Quiz"/>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and at last my ajax script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#edit_quiz').click(function (event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/quiz/1",
            data : {
                "quizTitle" : "${quizTitle}"
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#edit_quiz_title').val(data.quizTitle);
            }
        })
        return false; //for good measure
   });</script>
```

this opens up the dialog but there are some issues those are:

> 1. the data is loaded using the 
>      url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/quiz/1", I want to be this dynamic means Is there any way to get the id of  selected quiz from a list of quizzes and get the data accordingly in modal form?
> 2. the data is shown in the form input field when it is focused how can data be filled without focus?

My RestController

```
@RestController
public class AdminRestController {
    @Autowired
    private QuizService quizService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/quiz_list/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*",  produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<Quiz>> quizList() {
        Set<Quiz> quizs = quizService.findAllQuizzes();
        if(quizs.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<Set<Quiz>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<Set<Quiz>>(quizs, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/quiz/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*",  produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Quiz> quizById(@PathVariable("id") Long quizId) {
        Quiz quiz = quizService.getQuizById(quizId);
        if(quiz == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<Quiz>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<Quiz>(quiz, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in success callback you are try to get id which is not exist in your page

replace this

```
$('#edit_quiz_title').val(data.quizTitle);
```

with this

```
$('#quiz_title').val(data.quizTitle);
```